# Catalytic converters 2010 Honda accord v6 EX-L

Tags: honda, accord

How many catalytic converters are there in 2010 Honda Accord V6 EX-L and how many Oxygen sensor should be replaced as well when changing the converter.

Comment: Why do you want to replace any oxygen sensors?

Comment: I read it’s recommended to replace them when changing converters

Comment: As far as I can tell it has 3 cats, right and left and downstream, 3 02 sensors, one before and after the 2 cats and one after the downstream cat.